# Non-static equivalent to java.nio.file.Paths.get()

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

**Some Background:** I am running a Jenkins Shared Library in sandbox mode, and I am unable to use any Java/Groovy static methods. An easy solution would be turn-off sandbox mode, but I must use it. Another restriction: `new java.io.File(...)` calls are not allowed.

Are there any non-static functions/methods that convert a sequence of strings that when joined form a path string to a Path -- i.e. the behaviour of [`java.nio.file.Paths.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)?

**Edit:** I am aware of that it can be manually done quite tediously, but I would like to see if any existing function(s) exist to do this.

Comment: I think you can do `new File(...).toPath()`

Comment: @Ofek That would work only for a single string (My use case involves joining multiple strings into a single path) and would also fail if `...` does not exist on the system, which is different behaviour to `java.nio.file.Paths.get()`.

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't just quick'n'dirty it with string concatenation?

Comment: @iggy Theoretically yes, but I would have to do a lot of checking for slashes and other URI elements to make sure that the resultant string is actually a valid path (so for example, concatting `/home/usr/` and `/x.txt` naively wouldn't give a valid path). Just trying to see if there is an existing solution before I write my own.

Comment: @trevoryao, `new File("/home/usr//x.txt").toPath()` will return you a correct path without double slashes - you still can use simple string joins

Comment: another option: `new File("/home/usr","aaa/x.txt").toPath()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like under the restriction of Groovy Sandbox, there are no such existing function(s) that can imitate the usage of `java.nio.file.Paths.get(...)` without creating a new `file` object. The workaround I used in my specific case of converting file 'stems' (UNIX or DOS format) into a UNIX style absolute/relative path used messy regex matching and string concatenation. It does mimic the call of `java.nio.file.Paths.get(...)`.

```
def mergePaths = { String first, String... rest ->
    return first.replaceAll(/(\\$)|(\/$)/, '').replaceAll(/(\\)/, '/') + '/' +
        rest.collect { it ->
            it.replaceAll(/(^\\)|(^\/)|(\\$)|(\/$)/, '')
        }.collect { it ->
            it.replaceAll(/(\\)/, '/')
        }.join('/')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static Path getPath(String ... pathArr) {
    if (pathArr.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : pathArr)
        path.append("/").append(s);
    return new File(path.toString()).toPath();
}
```

I tested, its works for paths that doesn't exist

Comment: This would not work for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447566/non-static-equivalent-to-java-nio-file-paths-get#comment120968254_68447566) case. See my comment above.

Comment: The question includes "Are there any non-static functions" and "I would like to see if any existing function(s) exist to do this".  I don't think this example addresses either of those.

Answer (score 0):

```
println new File("/home/usr", "x.txt").toPath()
println new File("/home/usr/", "/x.txt").toPath()
println new File("/home/usr//x.txt").toPath()
println new File("/home", "usr/x.txt").toPath()
```

everything above gives the result:

```
/home/usr/x.txt
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but is unfortunately not permitted in groovy sandbox -- `new java.io.File(...)` calls are not allowed.

Comment: maybe you should go to jenkins admin and allow what you need?

Comment: unfortunately not an option :(

Comment: what about `build.workspace.child('/home/usr//x.txt')`